# How can I generate a limited access API token for SurveyMonkey?

Tags: security, surveymonkey

I'm creating a client-side application (i.e. HTML/CSS/JS in a web browser) that retrieves survey information from a SurveyMonkey account and generates an appropriate form to submit it. The application itself works fine, but it relies on knowing the API key to call `get_survey_list` and `get_survey_details`. The problem is that anyone could easily extract the key (e.g. by inspecting the network requests using the browser's debug tools) and perform more privileged operations like `get_responses` which is private information and thus should not be publicly accessible in this way.

Is there a way to create a "limited access API token" of some kind? For example, I would like to create one that is only authorized to perform certain types of API calls.

Comment: In case you're wondering why I want to use this approach rather than just share the `https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/XXXXXX` link or embed it in an iframe, I am trying to incorporate this into a website that is designed to be [responsive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your reasoning. The purpose of the weblink collector link is to collect responses from respondents, but get_survey_details and get_survey_list won't allow you to collect responses. There is API support for submitting responses; responses may only be collected via a SurveyMonkey collector.

Comment: @TonyMayse, yes getting the survey information is the first half of the problem (so that it can an appropriate form can then be presented to the user), but then I would need some way to be able to capture the results of that. Sounds like I need to go read about collectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, the only authorization token you can generate is a full access one as documented [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/guide_oauth).

Your best bet in this case is to have a proxy web app you can call, which then makes the API calls on the client's behalf.

Comment: Could IP restrictions be used to limit token-based access to privileged functions?

Comment: that's not a feature of SurveyMonkey's API, No